# javascript assign variable value when script.onerror occurs

Tags: javascript, variables

I am trying to assign variable value within script.onerror = function(){  }

```js
function CheckScriptThenDoSomething (){

  var VariableA;

  let script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src = "../Dummy.js";
  document.head.append(script);
  script.onerror = function () {
        location.href = '#ABC';
        VariableA = true;
  };
  
  //The problem is, at outside of the script.onerror, The VariableA  value is lost, I cannot use the value of VariableA to do something,
  if(VariableA == true){
    //The code written here never runs, the value of VariableA is null,
  }
  
 }
```

When script error occurs (eg. if script hasn't been found), location.href = '#ABC'; works fine but variable assignment: VariableA = true; never happens. I mean I cannot use the value of VariableA to do something outside of script.onerror = function () { } code block.

Can someone show me how to assign variable value inside script.onerror = function () { ... }?

Also, is there anything like script.onsuccess ?

Thank you,

Comment: I ran your code, and it worked fine for me. In regards to the latter part of your section, there is a method named `onload` that you can override.

Comment: You can also `try {} catch(){} ` or await fetch then... catch